# Overlay my application on top of other app and close the app

Tags: android, android-intent, overlay

I am trying to create an app that works on the same lines as app lockers, what i've achieved till now is when you open one of the predefined apps it opens up my app on top of it, but pressing back loads back the app that is supposed to be blocked! This is the code I am using, I don't expect it to work but I don't know how to achieve what I need

```
//If Application is open (this is done and works)
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("myapp.package.name");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

To reiterate,

1) My app opens when the predefined app is open 
2) Pressing back button closes my app and loads back the blocked app 
3) I don't want the blocked app to be accessible

Comment: what do you expect by blocking other apps by  placing your app on top of them ? Do you expect some input by the user and process it using your app and then do some thing ??

Comment: I dont need any input from user once I overlay, that is beside the point here, I just need both my app and the blocked off to be removed from the screen when I press the back button! Right now, pressing the back button causes the blocked app to become the top app and that again triggers my overaly

Comment: are you able to get the package name of "blocked app" ?